# check if an object have all the property of a class in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a class abc in typescript

```
export class ABC{
    public a : any;
    public b : any;
    public c? : any;
    public d? : any;
}
```

Now in my function I receive an input lets say `data:any`
Now i want to check if that input i.e data have all the required property of class ABC.
Is there any option to do this without using `hasOwnProperty` on every key of class ABC and object data.

Answer (score 2):

Instantiate the class to get all properties and use the **every** function to check if all keys are indeed in the passing object.

```
function hasAllProperties (data, YourClass) {
  const yourClass = new YourClass()
  return Object.keys(yourClass).every((key) => data[key] !== undefined)
}
```

Usage

```
hasAllProperties(data, ABC)
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR. Using `hasOwnProperty` is very likely inevitable, unless you’re absolutely sure about your function usage, input data source to your function is totally under control.

Longer version:

You must understand the difference of *static type check* and *runtime check*. TS is a static type checker, but it doesn’t have a runtime. Code in TS is transpiled to JS before execution, and run in a JS runtime engine.

The only way TS can check whether properties of `data` meet the requirement, is that piece of information must first exist within the type system. But in your case `data: any` has swallowed all meaningful type information, leaving TS nothing to work on.

Even if `data`’s type is more concrete, something like `data: { a: any; b: any; }` etc. TS can only check that, in your code base, you didn’t explicitly write any code that pass in invalid arguments.

If somewhere you write `validate(anyData)`, where `anyData: any`, then the safe guard is gone. Plus, it cannot guarantee in JS runtime, invalid arguments are never passed in.